# Using maven archetype to create an AEM project

Tags: aem, maven-archetype

When we generate a maven AEM project, how do we decide the archetype to use? What are the deciding factors and best practices for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the a baseline structure provided in Adobe-Marketing-Cloud space on Github - [aem-project-archetype](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-project-archetype)

This is a very basic structure to start with and provides you following modules -

- Core : Core bundle (java code goes here)
- it.launcher - Baseline bundle to support Integration Tests with AEM
- it.test - Integrations tests
- ui.apps - Module for your components,template etc code.
- ui.content - Project sample/test content or may be actual content (actual content in codebase is not a good practice)

Important thing to know prior to deciding the structure for your project is -

1. Is the implementation for multiple brands or to be used across multiple projects
2. Is there a need of platform which provides the basic/core functionality/features to be extended by different implementations
3. What is the roadmap for the project

That said, a best practice is to separate interface and implementation into different modules. Most modules will have 3 sub-modules (api, core and package).

- api: OSGi specification describes a modular system with separate api
  bundle
- core: An implementation bundle providing a service
- package: Packaging 2 bundles to generate AEM content package.

There can also be packages which consists of contents without api/service. Such modules do not follow convention of osgi bundles, for example configuration, components, design etc.

In most of the our AEM implementations, the project was generated from the com.cqblueprints.archetypes:multi-module Maven Archetype and its folder structure was refactored according to AEM 6 Implementation Guidelines.
All modules created are to organize dependencies in better way and have clean separation of package deployment.

Number of modules can vary depending on the project, some common reusable modules as baseline may include -

### **1. build-settings**

This folder can hold commonly used settings and scripts :
 - CI server scripts/setting 
 - Maven's settings.xml
 - Reusable bash profile specific to project etc.

### **2. Common Module**

This will have [api,core and content sub-modules]. As name suggests this should have generic service or utility classes that do not belong to any module or can be used across all modules. Be extra careful and justify reason for adding classes in this module else as a malpractice everything ends up on common module.

### **3. UI Module**

This will have [api (optional if you need OSGI services here),core and content sub-modules]. 
 - The core module holds all your SlingModel, WCMUse extensions and
   supporting Pojos.
 - Content package to contain all your UI functionality related to components, templates. Its important to structure this module correctly so that addition of components, pages etc doesn't make it unmanageable.

---

We created following structure in the content module, `/apps/<your_project>/ui`

- components : all components goes here. Further sub categorized as [content,global,scripts]
- install
- page : page components
- templates : page templates

---

### **4. Configurations Module**

This module to carry OSGI, Cloud Configurations and if implemented the /conf based implementations as well. Conf based implementation sample [here](https://github.com/nateyolles/aem-slash-conf)

- OSGI Configurations Module : Package module with all configurations as content.
- Cloud Configuration Module : Package module with all configurations as content

### **5. Sling Error Handler Module**

Any error handling content should reside here. Sample configuration has author mode display error stack and in publish mode it returns 404 response.

### **6. Designs Module**

Any error handling content should reside here. Sample configruation has author mode display error stack and in publish mode it returns 404 response.

### **7. Content Module**

Packages sample content and/or test content. In some implementations we chose to keep test content as separate module.

### **8. Complete Module**

The is the package module that gets compiled at the last and combines all the packages generated in above modules into a single package for deployment to the server.

If your application has lot of business logic or processing you could add up more modules, for instance in couple of projects we have following additional modules as well -

- Grunt/Gulp build
- Services/Operations (for business layer)
- Validations
- Data Import
- Incontainer tests
- Incontainer test content

In addition to these we created a pom project that abstracts all the dependencies, configurations, plugins, profiles  specific to AEM project and used that as a parent for the project POM. This cleaned up the project pom and allowed for reusability across projects for same client.

Sample `parent.pom` [here](https://bitbucket.org/atrikha/aem-parent/src/1184b879da3786c6e9748e85f84a24d44233c874/pom.xml?fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: sure, I will create and share a structure sample once i get some time.

Comment: Is the core module required?

Comment: its not mandatory, if you are not writing any java code, there is no need for core module.